# Как сделать перенос текста "завернутый " в badge?

Tags: bootstrap

В стили добавляю white-space: normal; - не помогает.

Comment: white-space: break-spaces; text-align: left; - работает. Если у вас не работает, значит нужно смотреть класс ".badge", он вам не даёт применить стили, вам нужно перезаписать его стили. Следовательно давать стиль "white-space: break-spaces" нужно давать именно классу .badge

Comment: именно так, класс .badge добавил white-space: break-spaces;  , но ничего не меняется.

Comment: Попробуйте поставить "!important". Если получится, значит вы не правильному классу задаёте white-space или bootstrap.css у вас подгружается позже основного файла стилей

Comment: что интересно, у меня badge-pill (с закруглением), но в этом css файле нет такого класса...

Comment: Ну получилось же?

Comment: Я не могу вам подсказать точно, так как не вижу странице, не могу посмотреть панель разработчика

Comment: Еще не работает

Comment: Значит нужно задавать стиль этому классу ".badge-pill"

Comment: Вообще хорошо было бы, если вы мне скинули страницу, где у вас эта проблема, я сам бы глянул

Comment: Стоп какой нафиг "white-space: wrap", внимательней будьте "white-space: break-spaces"

Comment: Нажмите правой кнопкой на бадже и левой на "Просмотреть код". Справа будут описаны стили этого баджа, скрольте их вниз и ищите "white-space: nowrap". Как найдёте посмотрите к какому классу он принадлежит. И этот класс и переопределяйте.

Comment: Вы можете тоже посмотреть? https://bvc.kz/autoparts

Comment: Нашел ссылку на файл, но у меня нет такого файла https://bvc.kz/assets/scss/_badge.scss  Точнее не видно, на панели папка коричневым цветом выделена

Comment: Прошёл по ссылке и работает же, даже !important можете убрать. Вот эта строчка очень хорошо переходит на вторую строку, когда не вмещается - "Автозапчасти на пикапы Toyota Nissan Mitsibishi "

Comment: Работает, да если галочку на панели у брать....но я ж должен это в файле изменить...а на хостинге нет такой папки, точнее ее не видно что ли...все галочки показать системные файлы итд стоят

Comment: Да не нужно __badge.css трогать. Я вижу вы написали в core.css - .label, .badge {
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0.35rem 0.5rem;
    white-space: break-spaces !important; - оно работает и перебивает то что в __badge прописано

Comment: Куки надо было мне аказыца почистить)  СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Badges */
.label,
.badge {
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: .35rem .5rem;
  white-space: wrap !important;}

.label-secondary,
.label-default,
.badge-secondary,
.badge-default {
  background-color: #66767c; }

.label-primary,
.badge-primary {
  background-color: #07a7e3;}

.label-success,
.badge-success {
  background-color: #0ad251; }

.label-info,
.badge-info {
  background-color: #85dff8; }

.label-warning,
.badge-warning {
  color: #384044 !important;
  background-color: #fce418; }

.label-danger,
.badge-danger {
  background-color: #f43a59; }

.label-light,
.badge-light {
  color: #384044 !important; }

a.label-secondary,
a.label-default,
a.badge-secondary,
a.badge-default,
a.label-primary,
a.badge-primary,
a.label-success,
a.badge-success,
a.label-info,
a.badge-info,
a.label-danger,
a.badge-danger,
a.label-dark,
a.badge-dark {
  color: #FFFFFF !important; }

a.label-warning,
a.badge-warning,
a.label-light,
a.badge-light {
  color: #384044 !important; }
```